# Disable and checked values of `CheckBoxList` memorized in database in c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, listitem

I have added in an form in aspx page this `CheckBoxList`:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Fruits" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Guava" Value="4" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="5" />
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

[image]

In this `CheckBoxList` it's possible select multiple values, e.g. :

[image]

And this values are memorized in field of database table:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Fruits.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (Fruits.Items[i].Selected == true)
    {
        FruitsUpdate += Fruits.Items[i].Text.ToString() + ";";
    }
}
```

Value memorized in database : `1;4;5;`

Now in aspx form page I need disable and checked the values of `CheckBoxList` memorized in database, but I have tried this code without success because all `ListItem` are disabled but not checked.

```
FruitsDB = dr["Fruits"].ToString();

if (FruitsDB.ToString() != "")
{
    Fruits.Text = FruitsDB.ToString();
    Fruits.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    Fruits.Enabled = true;
}
```

I need disable and checked in the CheckBoxList the items with value **1 and 4 and 5.**

Please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: On the second part of code, you are not selecting anything, you are just setting the checkedlistbox enabled or disabled.
What does FruitsDB return?

Comment: @PauloLima Thank you. The return of `FruitsDB` is `1;4;5;`

Comment: @PauloLima : I need disable and checked in the `CheckBoxList` the items with value `1;4;5;`

Comment: I've been looking around and aparently there's no built in way of doing it, but you can work around it with by adding the specific item with CheckState.Indeterminate. This "looks" like it's checked and disabled. However, as it isn't really disabled, you'll need to handle the ItemCheck event and stop the user from changing the checked state.
If you want, I'll post a solution with everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't set the `Selected` property of the list item where you set the `Enabled` property.

Here is the code. You will iterate over CheckBoxList. if current checkbox's value is in FruitsDB then it will be selected and disabled.

```
    var memory = FruitsDB.ToString();

    foreach (ListItem item in Fruits.Items)
    {
        if (memory.Contains(item.Value))
        {
            item.Enabled = false;
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand your reply; I need disable and checked in the `CheckBoxList` the items with value `1;4;5;`